# PHP Redirection with Message

Tags: php, session, redirect, message

I have a controller which displays and processes postback for a form. The controller redirects to another page once the form has been successfully validated and the data has been processed accordingly.

Redirection is completed with something to the equivalent of:

```
@header('Status: 303 See other');
@header('Location: ' . $redirect_uri);
```

What is the most reliable way for the controller to provide a message that is to be displayed on the new page? Is there a standard practice for this?

i.e. "Your account was successfully updated."

My thought is to place dynamically generated messages into a session variable, and to indicate a predefined message with a unique ID in the URI itself:

```
$_SESSION['previous-response-msg'] = "Account of '$user_name' was updated.";

or

$redirect_uri = 'http://example.com/other-page?msg=42';
```

Comment: I think this is entirely a preference issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One time message in session variable has worked fine for me. I don't see much of a problem here, especially for status type messages.

If you are using a framework, its quite possible this is built in. .

Comment: If the same user on the same sessions performs two postbacks at the same time, is it possible that both with redirect with the same message (even though message may have needed to have been different)?

Comment: I do this (saving message in session and displaying it (and removing it from the session) on the next page load) for an internal application. Works well. Only quirk is sometimes the user processes two pages in two tabs really fast, and the two status messages for both tabs appears in one tab, instead of one message in a tab and the other message in the other tab. For this to work, you need to save an array of messages in the session, not just one message.

Comment: @Carlos how do you map the right message to the right page? Using a $_GET query param?

Comment: I do not map the message anywhere. I just save it to `$_SESSION["msgs"][]`. Then it will display on the next page loaded, whatever it'll be, whatever tab in the browser it is. It's for an internal application, and the users using it know about this weird behavior, so for us it's ok. For a public website it may be not so good.

Comment: Also, because some misconfiguration on the server, each page takes at least 2 seconds to begin processing the request, so that's why sometimes the user can process two pages in two different tabs generating two session messages, but that should not happen in a normal environment.

Comment: So if I were to do something like `$_SESSION['msgs'][ ++$_SESSION['msg-id'] ] = 'blah'` and then redirect to `$redirect_uri . '?msg=' . $_SESSION['msg-id']` then each redirected page would contain the correct message? And then tidy up the msgs session variable as I go. Thanks for the idea, I think that this could work very well.

Answer (score 2):

Your second method is a great way to adjust non-secure page content. Wherever you'd like the message to appear on your page you could...

```
if (isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] == '42') {
    echo '<div>Your account was successfully updated</div>';
}
```

Simple enought, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Using session will allow more flexible messages, but either way will work. There's no 'best practice' that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use ajax and then add a success and failure callback which displays the response data from the file you sent data too ?

Comment: I use AJAX in certain places, but there are a couple of areas where I feel the change of page is quite important. Like when deleting a user account, I don't like to use AJAX for this kind of activity because I feel that the change of page emphasises the destructive nature of such a procedure.

Comment: Yeah true I suppose the user feels at ease when they know or it looks as though its happened